# How to return image in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

I have this code:

```php
public function showImage($id) {
    $item = File::find($id);

    return response()->file($item->file_name_and_path);
}
```

`$item->file_name_and_path` contains the following:

```
files/2020/04/29/myfile.jpeg
```

Now I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The image file is on local driver in this path:

```
{laravel root}/storage/app/files/2020/04/29/myfile.jpeg
```

How can I get the correct local path or simply return the image file with image HTTP headers?

Comment: use `return response()->with('Image_path',$item->file_name_and_path);`

Comment: Do you need file path or file url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Storage facade for this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function showImage($id) {
    $item = File::find($id);

    return Storage::response($item->file_name_and_path);
}
```

As you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L148), it will add the following headers to the response:

```
'Content-Type'
'Content-Length'
'Content-Disposition'
```